# A window which displays all the files(.txt, .docs, .docx, .pdf) of a folder/directory in python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

How to make a window which displays all the contents(.txt, .docs, .docx, .pdf) of a folder/directory in python and can be opened by double click in a frame in the same window.

Comment: What you are asking for is very complicated. It is easy enough to display all the content of a folder/directory but to be able to open all those doc types into a frame is probably not possible. I know tkinter can do text files and json files I am not sure about more complex file formats like doc, docx, and pdf. My experience with tkinter so far tells me its not possible with tkinter.

Comment: So, how can i display the contents of the directory in a window?

Comment: There is a build in method to search for files in tkinter. Take a look at [this page](https://pythonspot.com/tk-file-dialogs/) it will provide a few methods.

Comment: Mike I want to just list all the contents of a folder in a window , the article is about selecting a file or directory

Comment: You could use a method from `os` to called `listdir()`. This can assist in finding all the files and folder in a given directory and then append those names to a list or dictionary then add them to a window display you create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple example of getting the filenames inside of a given directory and displaying them as buttons to be selected from.

This example will only work with a directory containing only text files but it should serve to provide a good example.

Here I use the `os` import and use the method from `os` called `listdir()`. This will allow me to iterate over all the file names in a given directory. In this case my directory is to a folder that is on the same level as my `.py` file.

I have created a method called `find_text_file` that will create a pop up window using `Toplevel()` and then create a button for every file name within that directory. These buttons will run two commands. One command to destroy the Toplevel window and another will call the method `update_textbox` to append the text file to the text box on the root window.

Keep in mind this only works with text files. You may need to do a little extra to work with json files and even more for other formats. (Most formats are not compatible with tkinter).

Make sure you change `self.file_path` to be the path to your text files.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os

class MyApp(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = parent
        self.text = tk.Text(self.root, width=50, height=20)
        self.text.pack()

        self.file_path = "./TextFiles"

        tk.Button(self.root, text="Open text file", command= self.find_text_file).pack()

    def find_text_file(self):                
        self.top = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        for name in os.listdir(self.file_path):
            tk.Button(self.top, text=name, command = lambda n=name: [self.top.destroy(), self.update_textbox(n)]).pack()

    def update_textbox(self, name):
        with open("{}/{}".format(self.file_path, name), "r") as f:
            self.text.delete("1.0", "end")
            self.text.insert("1.0", f.read())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk() 
    app = MyApp(root)
    tk.mainloop()
```